# Quick way to find Rank of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

$A$ = $\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 &4\\
   5 & 6 & 7 &8\\
    6 & 8 & 10 &12\\
151&262&373&484
    \end{vmatrix}$

After some row operation $(R_2=R_2-5R_1),(R_3=R_3-6R_1),(R_4=R_4-151R_1)$ and simplifying we have

$A$ = $\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 &4\\
   0 & -1 & -2&-3\\
   0 & -1 &-2 &-3\\
0&-1&-2&-3
    \end{vmatrix}$
and I get rank $2$ from here

I always convert given form into row echelon form to find rank. But Is there any quick way to find rank? Row echelon form is sometimes time-consuming.

Comment: The third row is blatantly the sum of the previous two, so the rank is at most three. The same phenomenon occurs for a $3\times 3$ minor and there is an invertible $2\times 2$ minor on the main diagonal, so the rank is $2$. In some cases [this trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2156863/how-to-efficiently-use-a-calculator-in-a-linear-algebra-exam-if-allowed/2156909#2156909) might be helpful in reducing the computation time

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I am not familiar with word mod you used in your answer can you elaborate  that answer in simple language?

Comment: If you are dealing with a matrix with integer entries, the parity of the determinant is also the parity of the determinant of the same matrix, with every entry being reduced to $0$ or $1$ according to *its* parity. The key observation is that any *odd* determinant differs from zero, leading to a matrix with full rank.

Comment: Of course if you get an *even* determinant you need further steps to distinguish it (or equate it) to zero.

Comment: This is more or less the same idea used for factoring polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$: the factorization of a polynomial over a finite field always is a simple problem, so the factorization over $\mathbb{Q}$ can be obtained by "glueing back" the factorizations over a suitable number of finite fields.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks for your explanation but I couldn't understand it. It's because I lack knowledge. I'll be back after gaining some experience with linear algebra and will talk to you.